# Java: Search in ArrayList an element from object

Tags: java, object, arraylist, point, indexof

Let's say I have this:

```
    // Create arrayList
    ArrayList<Point> pointList = new ArrayList<Point>();

    // Adding some objects
    pointList.add(new Point(1, 1);
    pointList.add(new Point(1, 2);
    pointList.add(new Point(3, 4);
```

How can I get the index position of an object by searching one of its parameters? <strike>I tried this but doesn't work.</strike>

```
    pointList.indexOf(this.x(1));
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Didn't know how to explain. Forget it. =)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to loop through the list yourself:

```
int index = -1;

for (int i = 0; i < pointList.size(); i++)
    if (pointList.get(i).x == 1) {
        index = i;
        break;
    }

// now index is the location of the first element with x-val 1
// or -1 if no such element exists
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it worked as expected. Why I didn't think that before? Your answer was first of all. Marked as correct.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a custom loop to do that.

```
public int getPointIndex(int xVal) {
    for(int i = 0; i < pointList.size(); i++) {
        if(pointList.get(i).x == xVal) return i;
    }
    return -1; //Or throw error if it wasn't found.
}
```

Comment: `null` is not a valid return type for `int`.

Comment: Whoops, fixed. There's two hours of sleep for you.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Same as A. R. S. but in a method. It worked.

Comment: No problem! Didn't mean to post a duplicate, but got ninja'd :P